# Cached string lists convert to lists

Tags: python, regex, caching

I have cached lists that contains words. I download the lists from the cache memory as string types. Does anyone know how can i convert them to lists again?

1st list as string

```
b"['cat', 'dog']"
```

and i want it in this formation

```
['cat','dog']
```

as list.

I already try:

```
for lists in petlist:
    x = lists.decode("utf-8") 
    x = x.replace('[','')
    x = x.replace(']','')
    resources = b.split (',')

    if ',' in x:
        x = x.split(',')
    print(x)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval`, but it would probably be better to fix how you're creating or getting that cached data so it's actually a proper list in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate a string that contains a valid Python literal. To handle your data we need to decode the `bytes` object to a string. We can use the default UTF-8 encoding.

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = b"['cat', 'dog']"
a = literal_eval(s.decode())
print(a, type(a))
```

**output**

```
['cat', 'dog'] <class 'list'>
```